# Get EXIF information from a Quicktime Movie

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicktime, exif

For a JPG image, I can just use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex to obtain the various bits of EXIF information from the image. However, this API does not work with quicktime movie files.

What similar Cocoa APIs can I use to extact EXIF information from a Quicktime movie file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXIF is a standard for image files, not for movies. There's no EXIF information defined for movies and correspondingly there's no API to retrieve them from quicktime movie files.